# gitlab runner: kill another job with exit status 0

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, sh, gitlab-ci, jobs

I am using gitlab-runner on centos 7. I have created a pipeline which has multiple jobs. There is one job which goes on running and I need to stop that job from another job, So I kill that process (job) from another job using below command in the 2nd job (in the gitlab-ci.yml file).

```
script: 
  - ps -ef | grep ProcessName | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

When 2nd job kills the first, first job fails with exit status 1. I need it to be passed with exit status 0 as It is the required behavior in my scenario. So essentially what I need is to kill first job from another job but the killed job must give the status as passed and not as failed.

Comment: Passed status normally have exit status 0. So did you mean to write "exit status 0" in your 2nd last sentence? Also, please share excerpt from your .gitlab-ci.yml showing how a pipeline job killing another pipeline job because that is not a normal use case scenario for GitLab-CI. Quite an advanced use case if you ask me.

Comment: @Lukman thanks for the correction. I have updated the question. Actually I am stopping the first job by killing the script (or process) which is being executed by the first job. Code part is also updated in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by giving kill -2 command instead of kill -9.
Here is the complete command.

`ps -ef | grep ProcessName | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -2`